How to demodulate Binary Offset Carrier Signal?
I need to modulate and demodulate a BOC (Binary Offset Carrier) modulated signal.
I tried starting with:
data_bits_I = ... % Array of 1 and 0 values;       % Size = 100 000 x 1 double
modData_I = bocmod(dataBits_I, 10, 5, 2, "cos");  % Size = 100 000 x 1 double

The signal should be filtered with a raised cosine filter but I i try to use it, I get a wrong spectrum (differents from internet documents) and I get 800 000 samples instead of 100 000 as expected.
When the raised cosine filter shoul be applied? Maybe never?
Then I multiply the signal with the carrier and add noise.
signalComp = CarrierAmpl_I * modData_I + 1i * CarrierAmpl_Q * modData_Q;
signalTx = signalComp .* carrier;
rxSignal = signalTx + gNoise;

basebandSignal = rxSignal .* conj(carrier);

Then I need to demodulate it to recover orignal transmitted bits.
How this signals should be demodulated?
Thanks.

Is this BOC for GPS? If so I don’t think that any pulse shaping is applied. Can your question to add the links that you are referring to? That will add more context.

@DanBoschen Im' refering too ESA BOC link. I should obtain the same shape as Figure 7. I can obtain this without pulse shaping. Could this be correct?

Correct there is no pulse shaping other than rectangular pulses (see figure 1 and figure 2 in your linked document, this is what BOC looks like).

The OP referenced this ESA BOC document in the comments, and is interested in creating a modulation that matches the power spectral density shown in figure 7 and replicated below.

The document describes this as BOC with a sub-carrier rate of 10.23 MHz and a code rate of 5.115 MHz, but I believe the above spectrums are specifically for a sub-carrier rate of 10 MHz and code rate of 5 MHz (given the nulls in the spectrum occurring at 5 MHz, 15 MHz and 20 MHz.
BOC can be simply described as a unfiltered BPSK signal (rectangular pulses), multiplied with a square-wave sub-carrier. For the case of BOC(10,5) with a 10.23 MHz subcarrier and 5.115 MHz code rate, we would have the following example signal structures I show below for the case of cosine and sine formats. This should illustrate how the modulated signal can be created by multiplying the code sequence with the (square wave) subcarrier first for the case of the "sine" format:

The "sine" format uses a time alignment with the sub-carrier shifted a quarter cycle as specified by using the sign of a sine instead of the sign of a cosine, and illustrated below for the same "1 0 1" code sequence:

Further, since the BOC waveform is generated with rectangular shaped pulses, the spectrum will extend further beyond what is shown, to be filtered ultimately by the transmitter bandwidth in the satellite transmitters. There is less concern with restricting bandwidth since the power levels received where interference to other wireless signals could be an issue is well below thermal noise floors (so non-interfering), and having a wider bandwidth signal leads to better navigation accuracy, so I suspect the filtering to be very relaxed, balanced with considerations of managing transmit power efficiency.
We can generate BOC using "base pulses" that then get multiplied with +1 or -1 depending on the code chip to be transmitted. As we see from the example above for the case of the BOC sin format, the base pulse used for each code to be transmitted is "1, -1, 1, -1". For the case of the BOC cos format, the base pulse is "1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1" here using a rate that is twice as fast as that for the sin format (in order to create the offset as illustrated). We can determine the power spectral density for a modulated waveform from the Fourier Transform of the base pulse alone (applicable to BOC here, but also to other pulse shaped waveforms). I have done that to replicate the spectrum above using zero-padded FFT's of the oversampled base pulse (to approximate the rectangular waveforms transmitted prior to the final transmitter filtering based on the finite bandwidth of the transmitter in the satellite, with the following result (scaled to be the same PSD as the plot provided above). The python code for the plots is provided at the end:

The above was generated with a 10 MHz sub-carrier and 5 MHz code-rate as verification with the PSD plot provided.
Below shows the corrected plot with the sub-carrier at 10.123 MHz and code-rate of 5.115 MHz:

To modulate any real carrier, simply multiply the carrier by the +/-1 values as given by the example sequences above, for any specific code sequence.
And finally the extended spectrum appears as below prior to being filtered by the satellite transmitter chain (I am not familiar with the exact bandwidth or any specified masks to be used with BOC(10,5) transmitters).

As for demodulating Binary Offset Carrier, this MITRE paper "Overview of the GPS M Code Signal" provides a good overview of potential techniques and challenges in a receiver implementation for BOC.
The Python code I used for creating the power spectral density plots is given below:
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft as fft
# sine phasing
code_c= 5.115e6
oversamp=10
coeff = [1, -1, 1, -1]
boc_coeff = np.zeros(len(coeff)*oversamp)
boc_coeff[::oversamp] = coeff
boc_coeff = sig.lfilter(np.ones(oversamp), oversamp * np.sqrt(20*code_c), boc_coeff)
w1, h1 = sig.freqz(boc_coeff, worN=2**18, whole=True)    # zero padded FFT

# cosine phasing
coeff = [1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 , 1]
boc_coeff = np.zeros(len(coeff)*oversamp)
boc_coeff[::oversamp] = coeff
boc_coeff = sig.lfilter(np.ones(oversamp), oversamp * np.sqrt(80*code_c), boc_coeff)
w2, h2 = sig.freqz(boc_coeff, worN=2**18, whole=True)    # zero padded FFT


plt.figure()
plt.plot((w1-np.pi)/(2*np.pi)*4*code_c/1e6 * oversamp, fft.fftshift(20*np.log10(np.abs(h1))), label="$BOC_{sin}(10,5)$")
plt.plot((w2-np.pi)/(2*np.pi)*8*code_c/1e6 * oversamp, fft.fftshift(20*np.log10(np.abs(h2))),'r', label="$BOC_{cos}(10,5)$")
plt.grid()
plt.axis([-40, 40, -120, -60])
plt.xlabel("Offset with respect to carrier [MHz]")
plt.ylabel("Power Spectral Density [dBW-Hz]")
plt.legend()
plt.title(f"Code Rate = {code_c/1e6} MHz, Subcarrier = {2*code_c/1e6} MHz")


Thank you for the detailed answer.
For demodulation, I was able to recover the code chips using the opposite processing:
`% Data recovery dividing by square-wave
updata = x./squareWave;
% Decide output by sum
y = sum(reshape(updata, kBOC*halfcyclesps, []), 1)';
`
It's a naif solution but for the moment it could be enough.

Yes that's fine once you have completed carrier and timing recovery. Keep in mind the actual signal would be below the noise, so an actual receiver would be operating on the correlated outputs. GPS C/A code is much simpler for this since the autocorrelation of the code is one distinct peak in every code cycle, where with BOC you have multiple peaks.
